# JavaScript Animation Library... Recomendation

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm interested in people's 'real world' usage opinions/recommendations for a lightweight, standalone JavaScript animation library. So, no need for a 'full feature' JavaScript library like jQuery, dojo, etc...

Notes:
 - NO HTML5 canvas oriented libraries please (ex. processing.js).
 - Css3 support is a bonus but not necessary.
 - The more efficient the better!
 - If you feel like it, let me and other's know why you recommended what you recommended.

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with jQuery? Especially if included from a CDN, the overheads are minimal.

Comment: What are you looking to animate??

Comment: @ahren         There is nothing wrong with using a 'full feature' library like jQuery... BUT why not include one that is dedicated/optimized to handle animations if that's all I need?

Comment: @frenchie      Simple DOM manipulation. DIV, IMG, text, etc...

Comment: Then jquery. If you insist that it's "simple animations" then you should code the animation yourself. If you need a library then use jquery; it's really the best thing since slice bread!

Comment: @frenchie      jQuery is great and I would code the animations myself but I'm a full time student and this project needs to be done ASAP. Also, it's being done for free. Via Clark Pan's recomendation check out the comparison between jQuery and GreenSock's. The same animation on my machine runs ~30fps with jQuery and ~60fps with GreenSocks...  http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html

Comment: Doesn't matter!!! FPS are for geeks; humans can't process beyond 25 FPS. Try yourself, tell me if you see any difference.

Comment: @frenchie      BUT I WANT TO BE A GEEK!!! *cries hysterically*  

I'm just being silly :P  
Geeks are cool, that's why jQuery, dojo, mootools, etc. exist, 'geeks' or 'JavaScript Masters of the Universe' make libraries for us lesser 'geeks'... To make out lives easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would highly recommend [GreenSock's Animation Platform](http://www.greensock.com/v12/).

While i've not had to use the stand alone solution for javascript, this library has been invaluable to any actionscript animation work.

They have a very well structured library, which supports all sorts of different types of plugins.

The core animation library is blazingly fast.

Comment: Just looked into GreenSocks, pretty cool... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather odd that you would rule out canvas based solutions off the bat. It is designed (and works marvellously well) for exactly that.

Anyway, there is a way to animate using the DOM, which is really good for backward compat, but is fairly arcane technique. Annoyingly I read a good article about it recently but can't find it now. I will say that you are unlikely to find modern js gfx libraries that do not use canvas.

Comment: If you do find it please don't hesitate to post.